# Download and parse XML file from Firebase

Tags: android, xml, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I am creating an Android app which downloads images and XML file from Firebase.
The code for downloading image works fine

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs:...../sample.png");
Glide.with(this)
     .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
     .load(gsReference)
     .into((ImageView) questionImageSwitcher.getCurrentView());
```

But I can't retrieve the XML file and read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a file from Firebase in that way:

```
StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(FILE_NAME);
                    File destinationFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME);

                    firebaseStorageRef.getFile(destinationFile)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    // File downloaded successfully, do your stuff here using destinationFile variable


                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            // Something went wrong
                        }
                    });
```

and do whatever you want with it.

*FILE_NAME* is the file's name hosted on Firebase